# File name changed in Samsung S3

Tags: java

I have implemented one functionality in J2EE Program , where one can download pdf file and the name of pdf file is same as the name of article.

let say name of article is "ABC" , then the downloaded pdf file name is also "ABC.pdf"

Now , I tested this in many browser , working properly.

But, when i download file name with "AB~!@#$%^&*()":?><" then perticular in Samsung S3's all browser , name of file is "AB~!@.pdf".

I checked in PC then it works properly.

And one thing I replace all the characters which windows machine not supported with "_"

Comment: Are you talking about android application, or a general java program?

Comment: @piyush jaiswal : General J2EE program , viewing that in Samsung S3 browser

Comment: Seems like a browser-specific problem. It it doesn't support some characters, there will be not much you can do about it.

Comment: Got solution Samsung S3 does not support '#' & '%'